# When trying to create array from excel using phpexcel, it adds random spaces between array values

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

so I'm trying to create an array from excel list using php
my excel has these values between A1:A3 - value1, value2, value3

My code is this:

```
    <?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/libraries/classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( dirname(__FILE__) . '/Tellimus.xls' );

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5
$newarray=array();
echo '<table>' . "\n";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
echo '<tr>' . "\n";

for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
    $column=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue();
    echo '<td>' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";

    $newarray[] = $column;
}

echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";

print_r($newarray);

?>
```

And it shows as: `Array ( [0] => value1 [1] => [2] => value2 [3] => [4] => value3 [5] => )`

My goal is to get an array without having empty spaces as number 1 array and number 3 array and so on after every entry. **How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: Not exactly `random` when they're empty cells or part of a merge group... if you need to eliminate them, then test the value and don't add them to the array if they're empty; or filter the array after your loop

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried printing the array with json_encode($newarray); And it shows: ["value1",null,"value2",null,"value3",null]
When i tried to unset all the null values it made it even worse to this {"0":"value1","2":"value2","3":null,"4":"value3","5":null}

Comment: So how did you try to unset all the null values?

Comment: $del_val='null';
if(($key = array_search($del_val, $newarray)) !== false) {
    unset($newarray[$key]);
}

Comment: Quotes around `'null'` is a problem: you should be looking for a value of `null`, not a string containing `'null'`. Either `$newarray = array_filter(
    $newarray,
    function($value) {
        return !is_null($value);
    }
);
` or `$del_val = null;
$newarray = array_filter(
    $newarray,
    function($value) use ($del_val) {
        return $value !== $del_val;
    }
);` would be an easier approach to filtering the array

Comment: This makes my array look like this: ( [0] => value1 [2] => value2 [4] => value3 ), skipping [1] and [3]
I furhter want to use that array to be used in jquery, but because it skips them it doesn't work.

Comment: So what do you actually want? You don't want to see the empty entries, but you need them?

Comment: If you just want cells A1:A3 then use the worksheets rangeToArray() method to get just those cells you need

Comment: I need an array in this form ( [0] => value1 [1] => value2 [2] => value3 ) and i can't use rangeToArray() if I want to add more column entrys later in excel without having to change the A1:A3 value also in my code,can i? Or is there a function to find the last column entry? Thnx for help so far

Comment: Worksheet method `getHighestDataColumn()`

Comment: What i'm trying to do as a whole is to get a autocomplete search box which uses a huge list of suggested words from excel list

Comment: Ah of course, I already used that function in my first post code. I'll try to use rangeToArray() method then and will post how i did when im done

Comment: Well if you need to read a large Excel file whenever anyone types a character in the autocomplete box, you'll have awful performance; you'd be far better off loading it into a database

Comment: You used `getHighestColumn()` in your code example, not `getHighestDataColumn()`

Answer (score 0):

hope this help:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/libraries/classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( dirname(__FILE__) . '/Tellimus.xls' );

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5
$newarray=array();

echo '<table>' . "\n";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";

    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        $column=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue();
        echo '<td>' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
        if (isset ($column)){
            $newarray[] = $column;
        }
    }

    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";

print_r($newarray);

?>
```